# Capsule getting stuck on edge of block

Tags: unity, physics, 3d, platformer, character-controller

I'm making a first person game and when I jump and my character gets close to the top of the wall, the vertical movement stops, jitters, or suddenly snaps to the top of the wall.

[Video](https://youtu.be/em68KLicRgQ)

Here is my character controller code, [based on this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5n_hmqHdijM):

```
using UnityEngine;


[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private InputManager inputManager;
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 playerVelocity;
    private bool groundedPlayer;
    [SerializeField] private float playerSpeed = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float gravityValue = -9.81f;

    private Transform cameraTransform;

    private void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        inputManager = InputManager.Instance;
        cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
        if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
        {
            playerVelocity.y = 0f;
        }

        Vector2 movement = inputManager.GetPlayerMovement();
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(movement.x, 0f, movement.y);
        move = cameraTransform.forward * move.z + cameraTransform.right * move.x;
        move.y = 0f;
        controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

        // Changes the height position of the player..
        if (inputManager.PlayerJumpsThisFrame() && groundedPlayer)
        {
            playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
        }

        playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I also tried using other solutions by changing the physics material of the level and player, neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered, thanks to DMGregory for editing this, because if i didnt have those specific keywords i wouldnt have been able to find answer

[Fix](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1422941/character-controller-jitters-when-jumping-next-to.html)

In the character controller compoment i changed the step offset to 0

Comment: This is currently a link-only answer. Can you edit it to describe the steps you used to solve the problem? That way the answer remains useful to future readers, even if the link becomes inaccessible.